# Not sure if im understanding OOP and PDO. Trying to learn how to use it

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Im not 100% percent sure if im doing this right, can someone look at my code and just fill me in on what i'm doing wrong.

When I test the code nothing happens in the database, and no errors listed on the page.

This is the config.php file

```
<?php
// defines database connection data
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', '*******');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '********');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'BetterGamerzUnited');
?>
```

register.class.php

```
class Register {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        try { 
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch(Exception $e) { 
            var_dump($e);
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->conn->close();
    }

    public function addUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password, $email, $country, $gender, $ip) {
        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, firstname, lastname, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(), now(), now())";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $email);
            $stmt->bindValue(3, $first_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $last_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(5, $password);
            $stmt->bindValue(6, $gender);
            $stmt->bindValue(7, $country);
            $stmt->bindValue(8, $ip);
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->conn->close();
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'There was an error';
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is register.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'class/register.class.php';

$register = new Register();

$register->addUser('Andrew', 'McComs', 'test', 'test', 'testtest@test.com', 'usa', 'm', '192.168.0.1');
echo $register->addUser();


?>
```

Nothing is echoing to the screen, and its not going in to the database.

Comment: If you'd like to learn by example, you probably want to look at how a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is organized internally. It's probably a really bad idea to be writing an ORM if you've never used one before.

Comment: `"mysqli:....."` mysqli ain't a proper driver for PDO but an PHP extension for MySQL

Comment: `mysqli:host` should be `mysql:host`

Comment: You have 8 binds and 7 `?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?` add one.

Comment: `INSET INTO users` that's `INSERT`.

Comment: I was trying to cause an error, but I already updated that.

Comment: OOohhhhhhhhhhhh. k. I don't know what else to tell you then.

Comment: Fred, would this issue be that all the files are in different folders?

Comment: It is possible, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Fred, okay so I moved the file and the include is working now but im getting this error Call to undefined method PDO::bindValue()

Comment: Tweak it to this: `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare(); $stmt->bindValue(); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: Okay working on that, Also I would like to say thank you to all of you. Also one question should I use bindValue or bindParam

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure out what you want to do at this point. First you say that you deliberately want to thrown/cause an error, but then you're wanting to get a success, what am I not getting here?

Comment: I want to add the user, but I was trying to throw and error to see if it was making it to that point. I was to add the user to the database

Comment: @Sam How to I call the __destruct function. I tried $stmt->close(), didn't work. I tried $this->conn->close() didn't work. I tried __destruct() and that didn't work. THe updated code is above

Comment: `unset($register);` will automatically call the destructor function, just like `new Register()` calls the constructor function.

Comment: So class the unset function in the register.php file and not in the classes file right.

Should I call it in the try{}catch{} on register.php or after?

Comment: Correct. I would use `try/catch` statements in the `register.php` file when calling the `Register` class, similar to what @user2864740 said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue #1

You are getting mixed up with local variables and class properties.  In your constructor, you set `$conn = $this->mMysqli = new PDO()`:

```
$conn = $this->mMysqli = new PDO("mysqli:host=".$DB_HOST.";dbname=".$DB_DATABASE, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
```

And then in your `::addUser()` method, you try to access this `$conn` variable.  This variable is only locally available in the constructor method, and you should continue to use your class's `mMysqli` property:

```
public function addUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password, $email, $country, $gender, $ip) {
    try {
        $this->mMysqli->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->mMysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, firstname, lastname, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(), now(), now())");
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(1, $username);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(2, $email);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(3, $first_name);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(4, $last_name);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(5, $password);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(6, $gender);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(7, $country);
        $this->mMysqli->bindValue(8, $ip);
        $this->mMysqli->execute();
        $this->mMysqli->close();
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        return 'There was an error';
    }
}
```

---

### Issue #2

You are accessing your defined constants (`DB_HOST`, etc) wrong. They do not need a `$` like a normal variable:

```
$this->mMysqli = new PDO("mysqli:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

---

### Issue #3

Your `PDO` constructor should use `mysql:host` instead of `mysqli:host`. `mysqli` is a PHP extension to access MySQL, the database is still MySQL (for accessing via PDO).

<sup>*Credit to @Fred-ii-*</sup>

---

### Extras

- `function __construct() {}` should be `public function __construct() {}`
- `$this->mMysqli->setAttribute()` modifies your entire `PDO` connection, so it should probably be called in your constructor method.
- `return 'There was an error';` won't print anything on the page unless you do something like `echo $register->addUser();`. Check out how [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) works.

Comment: For some reason I don't think its connecting to my database, what try{}catch{} could I put on the $this->mMysqli = new PDO()'

Comment: For debugging purposes, I'd use `try { new PDO(); } catch(Exception $e) { var_dump($e); }` and then update your question with the dumped error trace.

Comment: @AndrewMcCombs see my updated (in the middle of the post about the constants) for a potential fix.

Comment: Sidenote: Usually, `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is placed under where DB connection is first initialized. @AndrewMcCombs

Comment: @Fred-ii- _"`$this->mMysqli->setAttribute()` modifies your entire `PDO` connection, so it should probably be called in your constructor method."_

Comment: @Sam OP has `mysqli:host` that should be `mysql:host` which is a contributing factor.

Comment: @Sam Scratch that last comment, OP changed it to `mysql:host` in the question just now.

Comment: I have updated the code in the post

Comment: @AndrewMcCombs your updated post is still missing some of the updates from my post, see `Issue #2` :)

Comment: @Sam Another thing I just spotted, OP has 8 binds and 7x `?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?` - the errors are just trickling in lol

Comment: I fixed issue 2 and the ?, look at the updated post

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address all the [little] issues; however, the code *is a wrong design*;

1. The connection is now embedded into the Register class - which represents a perfectly fine repository/access class in the [Data Access Layer (DAL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer). Such a class should *use* a connection, but should *not* own/manage a connection.
2. The connection lifetime is per the lifetime of each Register object because it believes it also manages the connection: with this approach each DAL type instance opens/closes a connection-per-instance. This does *not* scale as the number of database-using types increases.

A usable approach is to accept the connection as a [*Dependency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (ie. constructor argument) that can be shared between all instances of all DAL types and all database access within a particular request or an "isolated database task", eg:

```
public function __construct($conn) {
  // The supplied connection should be open, in a valid state, and configured.
  // Connection-specific attributes should not be changed within the DAL.
  // (And do not close the connection from the destructor.)
  $this->conn = $conn;
}

// Where $conn was already created appropriately and meets the above rules
$register = new Register($conn);
```

There may be cases when specific DAL types to create - or rather, be *given* - new/distinct connections, but that is relatively uncommon; additionally it may make sense for the dependency to itself be a factory, but such is a rabbit hole..

The DAL methods should use transactions as appropriate but otherwise *not* connect to, open, or close the database. *It is the responsibility of the program context and/or IoC container to manage connections and lifetimes.*

---

Also, I would encourage *not* catching errors in the DAL (except if they can be recovered from, ignored, wrapped, or otherwise handled appropriately), but also leave this to the usage-site. The usage of the catch/return is suspicious because it  is a "void" method otherwise. Consider rewriting it as so:

```
try {
  $register->addUser(..);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Failed to add user";  // Can be changed without mucking DAL, although
                              // I recommend a more MVC approach to `echo`.
}
```

If the DAL wants to include useful information in such an *exceptional* case it can *wrap* the inner exception and provide more detail. That is, the detail might be "username already exists".